# PyQt5 Designer. Getting a button event to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to get a button event handler working using Qt Designer.

I am using Anaconda-Spyder with Python 3.6

The form appears but the button `btn_browse` does not function. The line edit box has a cursor in it and you can type into it.

The Python file generated automatically from the ui is below. It is called `file_reader.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 320)
        self.btn_browse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_browse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 113, 32))
        self.btn_browse.setObjectName("btn_browse")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 120, 241, 131))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.btn_browse.setText(_translate("Dialog", "MyButton"))
```

The code I have used (pretty much from the QtDesigner Docs site) is

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from file_reader import Ui_Dialog
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Make some local modifications.
        self.ui.colorDepthCombo.addItem("2 colors (1 bit per pixel)")

        # Connect up the buttons.
        self.ui.btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)


    def browse_folder(self):
        #exit
        print("Hello")
        #self.textBrowser.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
        directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Pick a folder")
        # execute getExistingDirectory dialog and set the directory variable to be equal
        # to the user selected directory

        if directory: # if user didn't pick a directory don't continue
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory): # for all files, if any, in the directory
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  # add file to the listWidget




import sys        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Dialog() #Also tried QDialog() here
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't think the function `browse_folder` is being called. I think the issue might be the QDialog class being used rather than QMainForm. I

I am working on that. Also, I am unsure what the x switch in the ui convertor does.

I have looked at several answers here and can't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

- You are not creating a Dialog object, but a `QDialog` filled with `Ui_Dialog` that does not have the browse_folder method or the connection.
- `QFileDialog` is part of `QtWidgets`, it is not part of `QtGui`, you are probably using an example of `PyQt4`.
- I'm assuming that `listWidget` is from `Ui_Dialog` so you must sign in through `ui`.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog
from file_reader import Ui_Dialog
import os

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Make some local modifications.
        self.ui.colorDepthCombo.addItem("2 colors (1 bit per pixel)")

        # Connect up the buttons.
        self.ui.btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)


    def browse_folder(self):
        #exit
        print("Hello")
        #self.textBrowser.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Pick a folder")
        # execute getExistingDirectory dialog and set the directory variable to be equal
        # to the user selected directory

        if directory: # if user didn't pick a directory don't continue
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory): # for all files, if any, in the directory
                self.ui.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  # add file to the listWidget


import sys        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Dialog()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you mean that window = Dialog() should be window=QDialog() ? I have tried both of these.

Comment: @nerak99 Have you tried the code that I have proposed?

Comment: Hey sorry eyllanesc. I am not a frequent visitor here. After I commented out 'self.ui.colorDepthCombo.addItem("2 colors (1 bit per pixel)")' I got somewhere. Thanks. is the colorDepthCombo.additem() method from the parent class? If so should I call it via super() or something

Comment: Thanks for that 'Skandix'. How do I call QDialog method from within my class?

Comment: @nerak99 
QDialog is not a method, it's a class, what do you mean by calling it?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that Dialog is going to be an instance of QDialog. I am asking how I call inherited methods. I have done some OO with java (a long while back) and maybe asking a silly question.

Comment: Dialog is not an instance, it is a class that inherits from QDialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168284/discussion-between-nerak99-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @nerak99 I ask you to review basic OOP concepts, otherwise we will be speaking in different *languages*.

Comment: What main method do you want to call?